# Prove that M is flat if and only if each $M_i$ is flat.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $\{M_i\}_{i \in I}$ be any family of $A$-modules, and let $M$ be their direct sum. Prove that M is flat if and only if each $M_i$ is flat.

Comments:

I'm taking a homomorphism $f: N \longrightarrow N'$ innjective. I want to show that $f \otimes Id$ is injective.

Comment: Recast flatness in terms of $\operatorname{Tor}_1^A$, which behaves nicely under direct sum.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Doesn't this follow from the fact that tensor product distributes over direct sums?  I.e., $\left(\bigoplus_i M_i\right) \otimes_A N \cong \bigoplus_i(M_i \otimes_A N)$.

Comment: I was able to solve it, thank you.